# How to make a virtual attribute for a field with select:false

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using `select:false` to prevent the large amount of nested data from showing.

```
var Revision = {
    Timestamp : { type : Date, default: Date.now },
};

var Article = new Schema({
    Title: { type: String, required: true },
    Revisions: {type: [Revision], select:false}
},schemaOptions);
```

And I want to use a virtual attribute to show it's small part.

```
Article
.virtual('LastRevision')
.get(function(){
    var revs = this.Revisions;      //undefined unless select:false is commented out 
    if ( revs && revs.length>0) {
        return revs[revs.length-1];
    }
});
```

Is there any way to access the field with `select:false` from the virtual attribute getter?

Comment: Have you found an answer for it? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Me too. Any answers? @PabloDeNadai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, you can only access `select: false` fields if you force select them when you make the query:

```js
Article.findById(articleId, '+Revisions');
```

Note: don't use `lean: true` with queries where you also want the virtuals (this may help some people coming here).

More info/updates in [this github issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1596).